# How to join 1d list to 2d list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to add a 1d list to a 2d list at a specific index:

```
numbers = [
    [1,2,3],
    [11,12],
           ]

numbers[0].append([4,5,6])
numbers[1].append([13,14,15,16])
print(numbers)
```

what I want to print:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

what instead I get:

```
[[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], [11, 12, [13, 14, 15, 16]]]
```

Is there any other way to do it instead with Numpy? Otherwise how can it be done?
Thanks

Comment: `numbers[...].extend(...)`

Comment: If you did this in numpy, you'd be working with a jagged array, which is not recommended.

Comment: These are lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
numbers = [
    [1,2,3],
    [11,12],
           ]
numbers[0] += [4,5,6]
numbers[1] += [13,14,15,16]
print(numbers)
```

output:

`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]`